# Upload Custom VMware CentOS image to Google Compute Engine

Tags: vmware, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to upload VMware image to Google Compute Engine? I know its possible in Amazon EC2, but unfortunately I don't find any way to do the same to GCE.

Answer (score 1):

GCE doesn't support VMware instances. It only support Debian and CentOS. you can deploy any out-of-the-box Linux distribution including Red Hat Enterprise Linux (in limited preview now), SUSE and FreeBSD.

For further details, see the [Official Google Enterprise blog post](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-compute-engine-now-generally-available.html).

Comment: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-compute-engine-now-generally-available.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve the same as TC.

I'm looking at this route to solve the problem

Building a Google Compute Engine Image
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/building-image

and

Using custom images
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#installinganimage

But it sure looks to be very hard to achieve. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [qemu-img](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img) tool to convert a vmdk image to raw format?

Then, you can create a tarball: "tar -Szcf image.tar.gz disk.raw" and follow the [GCE image uploading instructions](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/building-image#publishingimage) to create a custom GCE image.

*Disclaimer: I have not tried this route yet.